# Printing array returns ( <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>) instead of array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So im trying to get values from user to then,check if their prime they get added to the array,then printing the array by using for i in range.Here's my code ( This problem only occurs while using numpy,I think)

```
from numpy import *
t = array([int]*10)
#Une fonction qui permet de saisir un entier compri entre 4 et 19
def saisir():
    b = True
    while b == True:
        n = int(input("Give the array length: "))
        if(3<=n<=10):
            b = False

    return(n)
#Une fonction qui permet de retourner vrai si un nombre est premier
def Prime(n):
    v = True
    while v == True:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if(n % i ==0):
                v = False
            else:
                return True

#Une procedure qui permet de remplir le tableau t par de entiers premiers
def remplir(t,n):
    for i in range(n):
         k =int(input("Give a number: "))
         if Prime(k):
             append(t,k)

#Une procedure qui permet d'afficher le tableau t
def Printing(t,n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(t[i])


#Une procédure qui permer de trier le tableau t a l'ordre croissant en utilisant le tri a bulle
#

n = saisir()
remplir(t,n)
Printing(t,n)

``
```

Comment: Very simply, `[int] * 10` creates a list containing the `int` class 10 times. Not 10 instances of the class.

Comment: You presumably want `[int()] * 10`. But `int()` just returns `0`, so `[0] * 10` is the usual way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

`[int] * 10` does not create a list of 10 integers, but it creates a list with an integer class prototype 10 times.

If you want to create a list of default constructor integer values 10 times, you can use `[int()] * 10`. Beware that the default integer value of python is 0 and it may vary by other languages. It is safer to use `0` instead of `int()` if 0 fits your case all the time.

The second line of your code should look like the following

```
t = array([0]*10)
```